# My VPS server is slow. Much slower than my share hosting

Tags: performance, vps

I have recently upgrade from shared hosting to VPS hosting.
But the VPS is much slow than the shared hosting. Any advice?

my website is www.sgyuan.com

```
top - 08:59:55 up 2 days, 15:10,  3 users,  load average: 0.52, 0.40, 0.36
Tasks:  28 total,   1 running,  27 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni,100.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1048576k total,   499848k used,   548728k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,        0k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
13782 mysql     15   0  157m  44m 6420 S   22  4.3 107:26.02 mysqld
19902 www-data  15   0 66396  12m 6916 S    1  1.2   0:06.69 apache2
19924 www-data  15   0 65928  12m 7120 S    1  1.2   0:07.39 apache2
    1 root      18   0  2604 1464 1212 S    0  0.1   0:02.46 init
 1155 root      15   0  2216  884  704 S    0  0.1   0:00.34 cron
 1203 syslog    15   0  2020  724  572 S    0  0.1   0:02.38 syslogd
 1264 root      15   0  5600 2156 1736 S    0  0.2   0:03.12 sshd
 7555 root      15   0  8536 2884 2276 S    0  0.3   0:01.83 sshd
 7567 root      15   0  3104 1760 1412 S    0  0.2   0:00.02 bash
 7735 root      15   0  8548 2888 2268 S    0  0.3   0:01.86 sshd
 7751 root      18   0  3176 1848 1428 S    0  0.2   0:00.21 bash
18341 memcache  18   0 43924 1104  808 S    0  0.1   0:00.02 memcached
19549 root      18   0 63972 8824 4960 S    0  0.8   0:00.13 apache2
19897 www-data  16   0 65652  12m 7008 S    0  1.2   0:06.78 apache2
19898 www-data  15   0 65896  12m 7328 S    0  1.2   0:07.16 apache2
19899 www-data  16   0 65932  12m 7328 S    0  1.2   0:07.29 apache2
19900 www-data  15   0 65640  12m 7320 S    0  1.2   0:07.60 apache2
19901 www-data  15   0 65676  12m 7048 S    0  1.2   0:10.32 apache2
19903 www-data  15   0 65672  11m 6568 S    0  1.2   0:06.38 apache2
19904 www-data  15   0 65640  12m 6876 S    0  1.2   0:06.32 apache2
19905 www-data  15   0 65928  12m 6800 S    0  1.2   0:06.66 apache2
20452 bind      18   0  105m  16m 2304 S    0  1.7   0:00.10 named
21720 root      15   0 17592  13m 1712 S    0  1.3   0:12.25 miniserv.pl
21991 root      18   0  2180  996  832 S    0  0.1   0:00.00 xinetd
22378 root      15   0  2452 1128  920 R    0  0.1   0:00.06 top
23834 root      15   0  8536 2920 2272 S    0  0.3   0:23.63 sshd
23850 root      15   0  3184 1868 1436 S    0  0.2   0:00.44 bash
29812 root      15   0  3820 1064  836 S    0  0.1   0:00.24 vsftpd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the web server config identical for the VPS and shared hosting configuration?  That would be the first place I look because it's not trivial to tune apache to perform well.  I'm assuming that with the VPS it is 100% your responsibility to configure the web server and you have to make the decisions about the number of clients, the process model, opcode caches, etc.